# Google Cloud Endpoints authentication using webapp2 sessions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints, webapp2

The client of my Google Cloud Endpoints API is an JavaScript (AngularJS) web application hosted on the same Google App Engine application as the Endpoints API itself. My users authenticate using [webapp2 sessions](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html) (datastore). They don't necessarily have a Google account. I want to be able to do a request to the Endpoints API like `/api/users/me` which would return the user data of the user who is currently logged in.

First I thought I had to implement a OAuth2 provider for my App Engine application, and then let the AngularJS application request a OAuth2 access token from my own App Engine OAuth provider (instead of the OAuth provider of Google, like the built in authentication mechanism does).

However, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786339/google-cloud-endpoints-limitations-any-proposed-solutions/19937334?noredirect=1#comment30947308_19937334) suggests not implementing my own OAuth2 provider but instead providing arbitrary parameters in my request (in a message field, or in a HTTP header) to the Endpoints API. I guess that parameter should be a user token (some encrypted value unique to the logged in user?). That value should then be passed to the browser. Isn't that insecure? I would like not to serve my AngularJS application on HTTPS if possible (to save costs).

Is this a good use case for OAuth2? Or is OAuth2 only for granting third party applications access to user data?

In case OAuth2 is not the way to go: how to pass a user token securily to the browser and prevent man-in-the-middle attacks? Should the user token expire after a certain amount of time?

Comment: To clarify my other comment further, I don't recommend rolling your own authentication at all. Doing so will be fraught with problems. When I referred to passing auth parameters around, I meant it in the context of other providers (e.g. Twitter or Facebook) giving you a token to identify the user. In most cases, those values are safe to pass to the browser via HTTPS. Most users will have one or more of Facebook/Twitter/Yahoo/Google/(insert other large identity provider) accounts, so deferring to those companies to handle auth is almost always a better idea.

Comment: Currently my application uses federated login and something similar to [gae-simpleauth](https://code.google.com/p/gae-simpleauth/) to handle auth. The user can login using a Facebook or Google account, or a username/password combination. So maybe I should no longer support the username/password (although I think many people are not eager to login to a website using their Facebook or Google account for privacy reasons). If I serve the AngularJS app via HTTPS then, I should pass something like `{ 'provider': 'facebook', 'access_token': 'TOKEN' }` to identify the user requesting an endpoints API?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you don't want to give up username/password auth you can do a similar thing by constructing a token when the user logs in. The token must have an expiration, otherwise it's equivalent to the password (which you shouldn't be passing around in requests and URLs).

Comment: But if the token expires, I need to provide some sort of refresh token as well. So isn't that the same thing as implementing an OAuth2 provider then? Why construct something similar to OAuth2 instead of implementing OAuth2? Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Or you could keep the token life small (say 5 minutes) and keep providing a new one and invalidating the old ones. It's important to make sure to do it right, though, which is why I still think it's better to defer to companies that make providing identity a business.

Answer (score 1):

I've just finished implementing exactly what you've described. Basically this method does the trick:

```
def get_current_session(request_state):
    cookies = werkzeug.http.parse_cookie(request_state.headers.get('Cookie'))
    sess_cookie = cookies.get('mc_session')
    parts = sess_cookie.split('|')
    if len(parts) != 3:
        logging.error('Cookie does not have 3 parts')
        return False

    signature = hmac.new(COOKIE_SECRET_KEY, digestmod=hashlib.sha1)
    signature.update('|'.join(parts))
    sig_hex = signature.hexdigest()
    if compare_hashes(sig_hex, parts[2]):
        logging.error('Cookie signature mismatch!')
        return False

    cookie_data = webapp2_extras.json.b64decode(parts[0])
    return sessions_ndb.Session.get_by_sid(cookie_data['_sid'])
```

And you'd call that from your API method using:

```
session = get_current_session(self.request_state)
```

You can find all the details at: https://blog.artooro.com/2014/08/21/share-sessions-between-google-cloud-endpoints-and-webapp2/