# How do I handle oAuth 2.0 in Google App Engine without using Google Accounts?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-oauth

I require oAuth validation for access to my Google Endpoint API backend. However, part of the oAuth flow requires the user to have a Google Account for authorization.

This would seem ridiculous to a user who created an account for my app and then had to authenticate it with a separate Google account. In fact, the authorization popup says something along the lines of (paraphrasing here): `This application requires your Google account to access data...`

How can I set up the oAuth authorization flow with my own users authenticating with their own app-specific accounts instead of a Google account?

**EDIT:**

Seems as though Google Cloud Endpoints doesn't allow for authorization without a google account: [Google Cloud Endpoints limitations... any proposed solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786339/google-cloud-endpoints-limitations-any-proposed-solutions)

Comment: You don't use oauth for your own app's auth.  It sounds like you are sending them to a url which is accessible only to your app's admin.  Where are you sending them where they get that message?  Is it perhaps to a url which you have marked as "admin only" or similar?  Do you have any templating package which has an auth system, like django,flask, etc?  If you use oauth to access the endpoint, then they need to login or authenticate via their google account

Comment: Your final line is the nail on the coffin. Looks like I've wasted cumulative days' worth of efforts into implementing something that Google just wants to use for coddling its own account holders. Great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Endpoints with another oAuth2 provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872240/google-cloud-endpoints-with-another-oauth2-provider)