# Google Cloud Endpoints and authentification

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints with Java and I want to create a login system for my users. What I want to do is very simple: I just want them to keep session once they have logged in using their emails and passwords.

However it seems to be very difficult with Cloud Endpoints. It appears that my users would have to own a Google account, which I think is a very important restriction, and it's not acceptable. I saw some threads like this one: [Google Cloud Endpoints limitations... any proposed solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786339/google-cloud-endpoints-limitations-any-proposed-solutions) but it didn't answer my question.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Authenticate Android End point without Google User Account is just impossible ! I tried every ways but still doesn't works..

So here is my way to resolv this problem, without any user interaction (Maybe not the right but that works, and you've got strong authentication (SHA1 + Google Account)):

**HERE IS MY ANDROID CODE**

**Get and Build Valid Credential**

```
  //Get all accounts from my Android Phone
         String validGoogleAccount = null;
         Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
         Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
         for (Account account : accounts) {
             if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                 //Just store mail if countain gmail.com
                 if (account.name.toString().contains("gmail.com")&&account.type.toString().contains("com.google")){
                     validGoogleAccount=account.name.toString();
                 }

             }
         }

        //Build Credential with valid google account
        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,"server:client_id:301991144702-5qkqclsogd0b4fnkhrja7hppshrvp4kh.apps.googleusercontent.com");
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(validGoogleAccount);
```

**Use this credential for secure calls**

```
Campagneendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Campagneendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential);
```

**HERE IS MY API BACKEND CODE:**
**API Annotation**

```
@Api(
        scopes=CONSTANTES.EMAIL_SCOPE,
        clientIds = {CONSTANTES.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, 
                     CONSTANTES.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
                     com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
        audiences = {CONSTANTES.ANDROID_AUDIENCE},      
        name = "campagneendpoint",
        version = "v1"
     )
```

**Method code:**

```
public Collection<Campagne> getCampagnes(@Named("NumPortable")String NumPortable, User user) throws  UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) throw new UnauthorizedException("User is Not Valid");

      return CampagneCRUD.getInstance().findCampagne(NumPortable);
     }
```

For the moment, it only works on Android (I don't know how we gonna do on IOS, without recode my own oauth2 API..)..

Hope It will help you !